# Table transformation

Tags: text-processing, scripting, python, columns, libreoffice

Looks like I hit a block with something I reckon must be quite simple.

I have a ranking table 1: (file 1)

```
Ranking  ID

1    A  
2    B  
5    C  
6    D  
12   n
```

file 2:
 A
    A
    A
    B
    B
    B
    C
    C
    n

I need to apply the ranking to another table where IDs are not unique and expect to get this
(desired output):

```
A   1  
A   1  
A   1  
B   2  
B   2  
B   2  
C   5  
C   5  
n   12
```

Can you point me towards a friendly manual ? ;) 
I would prefer to solve it in command line but Python and Libre office solution can do as well.

Comment: What does the second file look like?

Comment: Based on the information you have thus far shared, `awk` is probably the tool for this, but without seeing _both_ input files and the desired output, it is difficult to a> be certain, and b> provide a solution.

Comment: There is a join command that could work.

Comment: Thanks Rob, +1. Dead simple and works straight away, just join file1 file2 > file 3 gives desired output.  I wish I could accept this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
1    A
2    B
5    C
6    D
12   n

$ cat file2
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
n

$ awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[$2]=$1;next}{print $1,Arr[$1]}' file1 file2
A 1
A 1
B 2
B 2
B 2
C 5
C 5
n 12
```

Comment: This one works correctly too! Thanks Kamaraj, +1